# Filling a .mdb-File with Data through VB.net

Tags: database, vb.net, ms-access, dataset, oledb

i'm using oledb and DataSets on VB.net for filling an access database (.mdb).
It works in the following process:

- i have an existing .mdb-file with Data in it
- creating an oledb-dataadapter to the existing .mdb-file
- filling a DataSet/DataTAble with the Data from the file (adapter.fill())
- adding a new row to the dataset
- filling the row with data
- updating the dataset/datatable through the dataadapter to the .mdb file

This works so long, the problem is: I'm doing this process a few thousand times, with a few thousand datasets. From time to time, this is during longer and longer. I think it's because the dataadapter has to go through the whole database all the time and because i'm taking the whole dataset from the database all the time out, and updating it back to the database.

So my question:
is there an oppurtunity to do this in an other way? Without taking the whole data out from the database and taking it back? And without going through the whole Databse? Maybe with a sql-connection and then just adding a row to the end of the database??

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Is it maybe possible to create a DataRow with the Data and then just insert this row to the database?

Answer (score 1):

If You only adding rows - why not use `SqlOleDBCommand`? He has method `.ExecuteScalar()`

Comment: Just about to say this. As long as you can write the SQL INSERT statement for the new record, this would be the way I would approach it.

Comment: i need to add a row with DATA! how do i use .ExecuteScalar()?

Comment: i'm trying Oledbadapter, adapter.insertcommand but this also doenst work

Comment: Dim cmd as New OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO Table1 (Field1, Field2) VALUES (" & val1 & ", " & val2 & ")", connection) and then 
cmd.ExecuteScalar(). Also, you can use OleDbParameter with OleDbCommand

Comment: Have a look here for the documentation using `ExecuteNonQuery` (probably better than `ExecuteScalar` in this case): http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbcommand.executenonquery.aspx